# Applying formula to the first 2 columns of dataframes and showing the result in the 3 column through python

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, dataframe

So, i had two jsons files from where values were extracted into a dataframe and saved in an excel sheet

**JSON file1**

```
{
 "flower": {
    "price": {
        "type": "good",
        "value": 5282.0,
        "direction": "up"
    }
   },
 "furniture": {
    "price": {
        "type": "comfy",
        "value": 9074.0,
        "direction": "down"
    }
   }
 }
```

**JSON file2**

```
{
 "flower": {
    "price": {
        "type": "good",
        "value": 827.0,
        "direction": "up"
    }
   },
 "furniture": {
    "price": {
        "type": "comfy",
        "value": 468.0,
        "direction": "down"
    }
   }
 }
```

to create a dataframe and store into the excel sheet the code was

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('jsonfile1.json', 'r') as f1:              
    data1 = json.load(f1)

with open('jsonfile2.json', 'r') as f2:                      
    data2 = json.load(f2)


    

col1 = [data1['flower']['price']['value'], data1['furniture']['price']['value']]
col2 = [data2['flower']['price']['value'], data2['furniture']['price']['value']]

index = ['flower' , 'furniture' ]


df = pd.DataFrame({'value 1': col1, 'value2': col2, 'Test': index}).set_index('Test')

# storing into the excel file
df.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

now the output I want is: to apply formula [{(value 1- value2)/value1}*100] on column 1 and column 2 , where the result should be displayed in the third column of the dataframe , like this [in excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVUwX.jpg)

as, i am quite new in learning python, therefore I'm confused that how to apply formulas to the columns in dataframe. so , I'd be grateful if someone could help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the columns for your calculation:

```
df["col3"] = ((df["value 1"]-df["value2"])/df["value 1"])*100
```

Comment: this is giving error, can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong column names. Try the edited code

Comment: can you please share your running code because , the above correction is still not working and errors are observed

Comment: Can you be more specific about the errors you observe? I just import the jsons, modify the dataframe as you did and apply the posted line to get column "col3".